# How do I improve SELECT subquery in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, subquery, query-performance

I have a table Students and a second able Books. I'm trying to get a list of students along with the number of books they own.

```
"SELECT 
    StudentID, 
    FullName,
    book_count.ct
FROM 
    students
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        StudentID,
        COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS ct
    FROM
        books
    GROUP BY
        StudentID
    ) AS book_count
ON 
    book_count.StudentID = students.StudentID
ORDER BY
    students.FullName ASC
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

This query takes about 6 seconds to run and it will grow slower and slower as more books are added. Looking at the query profile >90% of the time is spend "copying to temp table". The problem is that my sub-select query that gets the count of books searches and total the entire books table regardless of how many students I might look up, 30 in my case. How do I improve performance on this? Thank you.

Comment: Is the DISTINCT necessary in the subquery? That probably doesn't help performance any. If the records in books are unique based on studentID and id, then I wouldn't think you need it. I'm also not completely sure that you need the subquery at all, but I'd have to test that. Seems like you might just be able to join books directly onto students, group by student id and name, then count book ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change that to

```
"SELECT 
    StudentID, 
    FullName,
    ( SELECT
        COUNT(id)
    FROM
        books
    where books.StudentID = students.StudentID
    ) AS book_count
FROM 
    students
ORDER BY
    students.FullName ASC
LIMIT 0, 30;"
```

Add indexes on FullName in student column
and StudentID in books table.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT StudentID, FullName,COUNT(books.id) AS book_count
FROM students
LEFT JOIN books ON books.StudentID = students.StudentID
GROUP BY StudentID
ORDER BY students.FullName ASC
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Comment: This works great but it doesn't return the students that don't have any books.

Comment: I made a test, and it return a 1 in book_count if it doesnt have any. You could replace COUNT(*) for COUNT(books.id) and it puts a 0 instead of a 1 when it doesnt have any books

Comment: Actually it works as expected, is way faster than my original query BUT the students with no books are returned as having 1 book instead of 0. Thank you, nonetheless.

Comment: please read my previous comment to fix the error when it has no books. If it helps, then please mark the answer as "selected" for the question